# How to handle and mock InterruptedException in Kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka producer returns **InterruptedException** while producing message in some cases. I want to know about the way to handle and mock **InterruptedException** for unit testing rise by Kafka producer. In below my producer code added. Thank you.

```java
public void MyProducer(String msg, String key)
      throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // statements....
  }
```

Comment: can you add the error message with stack trace

Comment: In some cases there is a chance of Kafka producer returns InterruptedException. So I want to handle and mock InterruptedException.

Comment: Can you show your code which cause `InterruptedException`. Usually you should interrupt current thread, or re-throw the Exception. Take a look at this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html